# How do I interpret this Scala explaintypes message?

Tags: scala, types, intellij-idea, scalac

IntelliJ with the "explain types" compiler option enabled emits the following error message:

```
Warning: scala <:<[Array[Z],Array[Z]] <: Array[Z] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]?
Warning:
Warning: scala: false
```

I suspected that IntelliJ was mangling `scalac` output, so I ran the compiler manually with the flag `-explaintypes`:

```
<:<[Array[Z],Array[Z]] <: Array[Z] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]?
false
Nothing <: A?
true
A <: AnyRef?
false
a.type <: Array[T]?
false
Nothing <: A?
true
A <: AnyRef?
false
a.type <: Array[T]?
false
```

NOTE: I've replaced the real type name above with `Z`, since it is quite long, and I suspect that it is not relevant.

Sadly, neither message explains much to me.  Can someone explain how to interpret these messages, ideally with pointers to documentation?  Googling for `scalac explaintypes` primarily returns message threads about people complaining that they don't understand the output.

Comment: It says that type (Array[Z] <:< Array[Z]) is not a subtype of  Func[Array[Z], GenTraversableOnce[whatever]). (A <:< B), defined in Predef, is a subtype of Func[A,B]. But Array, coming from the JVM, is not a subtype of GenTraversableOnce, so Array[Z] <:< Array[Z] is not a subtype of (Array[Z] => GenTraversableOnce[Z or anything else]). Now, it is hard to tell why the compiler would tell you that without looking at your code. Probably trying and failing to fill some implicit argument.

Comment: @DidierDupont: I was able to find `<:<` defined in `Predef`, but it offers the very terse description "An instance of `A <:< B` witnesses that `A` is a subtype of `B`", which doesn't help.  Is there a reference for this somewhere?  Unfortunately, `<:<` resists my attempts to Google for it.

Comment: search it in the stack overflow search bar, you will get quite a few things.